# contentView.isAccessibilityElement = true is not working on UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, accessibility, voiceover

have one UItableviewCell.
not able to perform cell selction with voice over on if I set isaccessibilityElement to true

contentView.isAccessibilityElement = true

If I remove this cell selection works.

any idea why this happens?